# extra 0 digit when trying to add 2 arrays

Tags: java

I am working on a program that needs to calculate the sum of 2 large integers without using the biginteger class in java. I am stuck on my for loop which calculates the sum. I am getting an extra 0 so 30 + 30 = 600.

I am pretty sure it is because I am looping through the arrays the wrong way. I need to go the opposite way (starting from the right side like you would when adding numbers) but I can't seem to fix it without getting an out of array index error.

here is my code:

```
main:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class testLargeInteger
{



public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String string1;
        String string2;
        int exp =0;


        System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
        //Store up the input string “string1” entered by the user from the keyboard.
        string1 = input.next(); 

        LargeInteger firstInt = new LargeInteger(string1);

        System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
        string2 = input.next(); 
        //Store up the input string “string2” entered by the user from the keyboard.
        LargeInteger secondInt = new LargeInteger(string2);

        System.out.print("Enter the exponential integer: ");
        //Store up the input integer “exp” entered by the user from the keyboard.
        exp = input.nextInt(); 


        LargeInteger sum = firstInt.add(secondInt);

        System.out.printf ("First integer: %s \n", firstInt.display());
        System.out.println("Second integer: " + secondInt.display());
        System.out.println(" Exponent: " + exp);

        System.out.printf (" Sum = %s \n", sum.display());

    }
}
```

Large integer:

```
public class LargeInteger {


    private int[] intArray;


    //convert the strings to array
    public LargeInteger(String s) { 
         intArray = new int[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10); // in base 10
        }
    }

    public LargeInteger( int[] array ) { 
         intArray = array;
    }

    //display the strings
    public String display() {           
          String result="";

          for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
            result += intArray[i];
          }
          return result.toString();
        }   

    //get first array
    public int[] getIntArray() {
           return intArray;
        }

    //ADD method to add 2 arrays together
    public LargeInteger add(LargeInteger secondInt){

        int[] otherValues = secondInt.getIntArray();

        int maxIterations = Math.min(intArray.length, otherValues.length);
        int currentResult; //to store result 
        int[] resultArray = new int[Math.max(intArray.length, otherValues.length) +1 ];

        int needToAdd = 0; //to store result should be added next step

        for(int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
            currentResult = intArray[i] + otherValues[i];
            resultArray[i] = currentResult % 10 + needToAdd; //if more than 9 its correct answer
            needToAdd = currentResult / 10; //this is what you need to add on next step
        }

        resultArray[Math.max(intArray.length, otherValues.length) ] = needToAdd;

        return new LargeInteger( resultArray );

    }

}
```

I have tried changing the for loop in sum to something like this:

```
for(int i = maxIterations; i >= 0; i--)
```

Comment: Vote to close: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Arrays in Java are 0 based. The valid indices of an array are [0, array.length - 1].

Comment: I didn't see it as asking to spot an error really.. Though maybe it is.. I just don't know if I am even on the right track and if it is for sure that I need to loop the opposite way..

Comment: @Sackling: That's why you should use the debugger; you can step through your program line-by-line, and observe changes in the values of variables, etc.  You can use them to tell if what you coded matched what you expected to happen.

Comment: If you add 1000 with 10 in your code, your result would be 10 an not 1010. And if you add 1090 with 20, your result will be 110, because of max iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That for loop is only one of your problems.

1] you are not adding the carry properly.

2] a stack is more appropriate here than an array.

With a stack (place code inside your method): 
Note: You are calling the function with number.add(num2);

```
public class LargeInt{
   private String number;
   public LargeInt(String num){
      this.number = num;
   }

  public String add(String num2){
    Stack<Integer> adder = toIntegerStack(this.number);//UPDATE
    Stack<Integer> addend = toIntegerStack(num2);//UPDATE
    Stack<Integer> result = new Stack<Integer>();

    int carry =0;
    int tmp = 0;

  while(!.adder.isEmpty && !addend.isEmpty()){
   tmp = adder.pop()+addend.pop()+carry;
   if(tmp > 10){
     carry = tmp/10;
     tmp%=10;
   }else{
     carry=0;
   }
   result.push(tmp);
  }//while

  while(!adder.isEmpty){
    tmp = adder.pop()+carry;
    if(tmp > 10){
     carry = tmp/10;
     tmp%=10;
   }else{
     carry=0;
   }
   result.push(tmp);
  }//while

  while(!addend.isEmpty){
    tmp = addend.pop()+carry;
    if(tmp > 10){
     carry = tmp/10;
     tmp%=10;
   }else{
     carry=0;
   }
   result.push(tmp);
 }//while

//beyond this point the result is your answer
//here convert your stack to string before returning
}
}
```

UPDATE TO ANSWER COMMENT:
I am also editing above to call this function to fill stacks.

```
private Stack<Integer> toIntegerStack(String n){
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    for(char c: n.toCharArray())
      stack.push(c-48);//ASCII
    return stack;
 }//toStack(String)
```

---

If you insist on using array, you must follow the same pattern with your array.

```
 int indexA=0;
 int indexB=0;
 int[] result = new int[1+A.length>B.length?A.length:B.length];
 int indexResult=result.length-1;

 while(indexA < A.length && indexB <B.length){//inside is same idea
    tmp = A[indexA++] + B[indexB++] + carry;
    //... do here as for stacks for tmp and carry
    result[indexResult--];
 }

 while(indexA < A.length){
    //do as in stack version
 }

  while(indexB < B.length){
    //do as in stack version
 }
```

Comment: yes after trying to fix just the for loop it has become clear I have other problems. I am looking at your stack now. I do not need to use arrays I was just more comfortable with them (imagine that..) I like the looks of using the stack. And I think I should know this but how is the adder and addend supposed to be populated?

Comment: see the new updates for some clarity. I created a private function which is called twice by the add method.

Comment: A couple questions, I dont understand how that private function works? What is the c-48? I have never seen anything like that and fear it is beyond the scope of our course. I also see you created a public class LargeInt is that supposed to be part of the LargeInteger class instead that I already have?

Comment: c-48? this is just an example. You can use Integer.parseInt(c+""), which would treat each char as a string of size 1. And yes the class is to show you constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your adding code assumes that the least significant digit is in `array[0]`, but your reading code puts the most significant digit there. You should reverse the array after reading.

Comment: No, I meant the constructor taking a `String`. You're putting the digits from the string into the array starting from index 0. And in your adding code, you're propagating the carry from index 0 to higher indices. Since numbers are written most significant digit first, that doesn't fit together.

Comment: hmm so I changed my for loop for the string constructor to: for (int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0 ; i--) and I am still getting the exact same result.. I am not even sure how that makes sense since it should be going backwards?

Comment: You must traverse the String and the digit array in different directions. `for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) { array[i] = s.CharAt(s.length()-1-i); }`.

Comment: So is that  for loop within the for loop?

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to convert (and typo'ed `charAt`). Replace `s.CharAt(s.length()-1-i)` with `Character.digit(s.charAt(s.length()-1-i),10)`. That's the only thing in the constructor except for the array allocation.